# Can you use Cordova with a web app?

Tags: jsp, cordova

I am working on a mobile web app with Cordova. The web app basically takes the user to a website within the webview. Currently the web site front end is made up of jsps with some javascript. I was wondering if you could use Cordova from the jsp since it inevitably gets converted to html.

Comment: I don't see why this was downvoted. I have done quite a bit of research with Cordova. I have played with Cordova and understand what it is. I read somewhere that it can be done and I thought since you can embed javscript within a jsp that it might be possible.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot use JSP templates as Cordova views. They require server to handle them and Cordova isn't such. You can always though retrieve the HTML generated from JSPs from server somewhere on web but it isn't how Cordova is intended to be used. You should also see the last Q&A on [PhoneGap FAQ](http://phonegap.com/about/faq/):

> Q: Can you use PHP/ASP/JSF/Java/.NET with PhoneGap?
>
> A: A PhoneGap application may only use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. However, you can make use of network protocols (XmlHTTPRequest, Web Sockets, etc) to easily communicate with backend services written in any language. This allows your PhoneGap app to remotely access existing business processes while the device is connected to the Internet.

Comment: I was able to use cordova code within a jsp successfully

Answer (score -1):

If you have a web app coded in a mix of HTML, JavaScript, CSS and JSP files and you want to port it to Cordova with real fast with a minimum of change, you could in principle split each JSP page by putting the static `<html>`, `<head>` prefix into a "static" HTML page, and keeping the content of the `<body>` tag in a new JSP file.

Code a service JavaScript function that you include in the `<head>` section to invoke the JSP segment through AJAX, take its results, and inject them into the "static" HTML page with:

```
<br>
    document.body.innerHTML = AJAXreturnString;
<br>
```

Yes, it's a hack, it's not how Cordova is meant to be used, etc. But hey, once you pass functional test that becomes the maintenance team's problem.